# Как правильно добавлять несколько значений в значении словаря python?

Tags: python, словари

Я не требую сейчас помочь мне с какой-то задачей, у меня просто довольно простой вопрос, на который я не смог найти ответ. Допустим, у меня есть словарь *colors* с ключом *color*;

```
colors = {}
color[color] = ''
```

И допустим, я хочу добавлять в него различные строки, с названием цветов, по одному. Но как это сделать? если просто +=, то они будут слитны, а += ", " + "цвет", как то не очень я думал, может есть другой, нормальный способ?

```
На вводе:
    белый
    синий
    красный
выход:
    белый, синий, красный
```

Answer (score 2):

Храните в значении список. Тогда добавляемые цвета будут отдельными элементами и их потом будет легко использовать как по-отдельности, так и вместе.

```
colors = {}
color = 'Какой-то ключ'

colors[color] = []
colors[color].append('белый')
colors[color].append('синий')
colors[color].append('красный')

print(', '.join(colors[color]))  # Напечатает: белый, синий, красный
```

Comment: Гениально, а то я почему то когда юазл append, выводилась ошибка, мол у словарей нет append. ведать в список не перевел

Comment: еще можно вроде
colors[color] += ['белый']